# Access .STP egde coordinates with PythonOCC

Tags: opencascade, freecad, pythonocc

I have a .STP file where I marked an edge to be welded using Solidworks, and then I exported the file as step 242.

The exported.STP file has this line:

```
#30=TESSELLATED_SHELL('Weld Bead1',(#27,#28,#29),$);
```

When I open the file on e-drawing the result is this:

[image: Image on e-Drawing]

I want to know if it is possible to extract the coordinates of the marked edge, e.g.:
vertex_1 (0.0.0) and vertex_2 (0.300.0)

Then, I want to save those coordinates in a json file.

Is this possible with PythonOCC? I've tried FreeCAD, but the weld information is not there:

[image: image in FreeCAD]

Any help would be appreciated.